# How to run my android reminder application running even thought i exit from it

Tags: android

How to run my reminder application in background even if exit from the application.
   My reminder application works fine when it is continue,but if i exit from the application it will not show my desired output.So,is there any way to run may application in background OR any service using that i make my application as service OR anything else.

Plz help me

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate the non-UI component and run it as service.